# NServiceBus endpoint is not starting on Azure Service Fabric local cluster

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, nservicebus

I have a .NetCore stateless WebAPI service running inside Service Fabric local cluster.

```
 return Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When I'm trying to start NServiceBus endpoint, I'm getting this exception :

Access to the path 'C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_0\AppType_App10\App.APIPkg.Code.1.0.0.diagnostics' is denied.

How can it be solved ? VS is running under administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open folder properties Security tab
2. Select ServiceFabricAllowedUsers
3. Add Write permission

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is because the folder you are trying to write to is not supposed to be written by your application.

The package folder is used to store you application binaries and can be recreated dynamically whenever an application is hosted in the node.

Also, the binaries are reused by multiple service instances running on same node, so it might compete to use the files by different instances.

You should instead instruct your application to write to the `WorkFolder`,

```
public Stateless1(StatelessServiceContext context): base(context)
{
   string workdir = context.CodePackageActivationContext.WorkDirectory;
}
```

The code above will give you a path like this:

`'C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_0\AppType_App10\App.APIPkg.Code.1.0.0.diagnostics\work'`

This folder is dynamic, will change depending on the node or instance of your application is running, when created, your application should already have permission to write to it.

For more info, see:

[how-do-i-get-files-into-the-work-directory-of-a-stateless-service?forum=AzureServiceFabric](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3d7b0d30-b084-4253-9a3e-49f9f1b9c1b2/how-do-i-get-files-into-the-work-directory-of-a-stateless-service?forum=AzureServiceFabric)