# NService Bus Access Denied when logging within service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, nservicebus

I have an issue that has come up out of nowhere in NServiceBus

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path 'd:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\PATH\.diagnostics' is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at NServiceBus.HostStartupDiagnostics.BuildDefaultDiagnosticsWriter(ReadOnlySettings settings)
   at NServiceBus.HostStartupDiagnostics.GetDiagnosticsWriter(ReadOnlySettings settings)
   at NServiceBus.HostStartupDiagnostics.Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context)
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureInfo featureInfo, List`1 featuresToActivate, IConfigureComponents container, PipelineSettings pipelineSettings, RoutingComponent routing, ReceiveConfiguration receiveConfiguration)
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(IConfigureComponents container, PipelineSettings pipelineSettings, RoutingComponent routing, ReceiveConfiguration receiveConfiguration)
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Inspired.CommonConfiguration.<ApplyEndpointConfigurationAndStartEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Inspired.TradingPlatform\src\Inspired.TradingPlatform.NServiceBus\Extensions\CommonConfiguration.cs:line 113
```

How can I set the permissions to allow the log file to be created?

I have never had this issue before, no idea why it has suddenly started

I dont even want logging really, so I am happy to just disable it, I just any solution to get round this error as I need to get on with other stuff

I have tried the logic below to disable logging but it has not made any difference

This is called BEFORE I start up my end point

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.Use<NLogFactory>();
```

This is happening on a local 1 node dev cluster.  It looks like this is being run under network service account.  This user has full permissions

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your application does not have permission to write in the folder `d:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\PATH\.diagnostics`

You should configure the logger to use your application work directory for storing thse logs, take a look on this other SO question: 
[NServiceBus endpoint is not starting on Azure Service Fabric local cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491529/nservicebus-endpoint-is-not-starting-on-azure-service-fabric-local-cluster/51502247#51502247)

Keep in mind, that the folder is temporary and can be deleted at any point when you service is removed from the node.